# R, change an element in an array what is in a list

Tags: r, arrays, list

I have a list like this:

```
l<-list(array1,array2,array3)
```

I want to change one element in the first array, my first thought was this:

```
list[1][1,1,1]<-2
```

But it doesnt work, because dimension issue.

What can i do?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please share some reproducible example of your data. Share the output of `dput(list)` in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `[[]]` to access the elements in list, i.e.,

```
l[[1]][1,1,1] <- 2
```

**Example**

```
array1 <- array(1,c(1,2,3))
array2 <- array(3,c(2,1,3))
array3 <- array(5,c(2,3,1))
l<-list(array1,array2,array3)

> l
[[1]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1


[[2]]
, , 1

     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    3

, , 2

     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    3

, , 3

     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    3


[[3]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    5    5
[2,]    5    5    5
```

and `l[[1]][1,1,1] <- 2` will give you

```
> l
[[1]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1


[[2]]
, , 1

     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    3

, , 2

     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    3

, , 3

     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    3


[[3]]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    5    5
[2,]    5    5    5
```